# Multiple attributes in updateOrCreate array (Eloquent)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a new row if there isn't one yet with the following condition:

`['employee_id' => $id, 'competence_id' => $getCompetenceKey]`

or if it exists already, I update it and set `['value' => $getCompetenceValue]`

So I did this:

```
foreach($request->input('competence') as $getCompetenceKey => $getCompetenceValue) {
    EmployeeCompetence::updateOrCreate(
     ['employee_id' => $id,'competence_id' => $getCompetenceKey],
     ['value' => $getCompetenceValue]
    );
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work properly:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ndQt.png

I could do it like this though:

```
foreach ($request->input('competence') as $getCompetenceKey => $getCompetenceValue) {
    $e = EmployeeCompetence::where('employee_id', $id)->where('competence_id', $getCompetenceKey);
    if ($e->count() > 0) {
        $e->update(['value' => $getCompetenceValue]);
    } else {
            EmployeeCompetence::create(['employee_id' => $id,
                                      'competence_id' => $getCompetenceKey, 
                                              'value' => $getCompetenceValue]);
    }
}
```

But I really want to know why the updateOrCreate() function didn't work for me.

Thanks,

Kenny

Comment: What error laravel gives while updateOrCreate ?!

Comment: @HirenMakwana no error, just wrong query.

Comment: Thanks check my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The first column is for update, but it should be also passed in the create function.

Example:

```
EmployeeCompetence::updateOrCreate(
    [
      'employee_id'   => $id, 
      'competence_id' => $getCompetenceKey
    ],
    [
      'value'         => $getCompetenceValue,
      'employee_id'   => $id, 
      'competence_id' => $getCompetenceKey
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it doesn't seem to fix it. Got the same queries :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work or not but as per my understanding.

**updateOrCreate** takes **$primaryKey** field as a query.

I'm not sure, may be this will solve your problem.
Add below line in your model file and then try

```
protected $primaryKey = ['employee_id', 'competence_id'];
```

Comment: Getting:  ErrorException (E_WARNING)
Illegal offset type

Comment: Yes, Need to override some properties, You can find solutions here.. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355#issuecomment-161376267

Comment: Declaration of App\EmployeeCompetence::setKeysForSaveQuery(App\Builder $query) should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setKeysForSaveQuery(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query)

Comment: Have you set public $incrementing = false; ?!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced issue with  updateOrCreate method .

```
$user = user::updateOrCreate(
    ['email' =>  'xxx'],
    [
        'location' => 'yyy' ,
    ],
);
```

first I don't need to pass 'email' in 2nd element of argument.
we need to create a fillable variable in model class with fields which we want to update .

```
protected $fillable = ['email' ,'location' ,'column1' ,'colun2'];
```

this worked for me so thought to post here.thanks.